# int array to string array

Tags: java, arrays, string, integer

I need to read a series of integers from a file and then convert them into an identical string array.

Here is my code for reading the file (which currently isn't doing its job).

```
    public void readFile(){
    while(scanner.hasNext()){
        for(int i = 0; i < 5;i++){
            intArray[i] = scan.nextInt();
            int temp = intArray[i];
            String att = Integer.toString(temp);
            stringArray[i]=att;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stringMap));
}
```

And the text file looks something like this

```
1 2 0 0 0
4 0 3 0 0
0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0
0 2 0 0 4
```

How would I go around converting this file into a string array?

edit:

following method;

```
public void readFile(){
    while(scan.hasNext()){
        for(int i = 0; i < 5;i++){
            intMap[i] = scan.nextInt();
            String temp = Arrays.toString(intMap);
            stringMap[i]=temp;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stringMap));
}
```

returns following String array [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]] instead of the desired numbers from the text file

Comment: What do you expect your `String` array to look like? What isn't working with your current solution?

Comment: forgive me if I am wrong, but you can simply `readLine()` which will give you directly the `String` representation of the row

Comment: You can use next() instead of nextInt() to get the next "word"(in this case number) as a string and store directly to String[] that is unless you want an int[] and String[] array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a matrix you want to store. Thus you need a two dimensional Array `String array[][]`.
The First index is the row, the second index is the column.
While you read your data with `scanner.hasNext()` you need to increment the first index counter.

Something like this

```
// 'rows' means the count of your rows which you are going to read.
// if you don't know the rows you need to use a List instead
String[][] matrix = new String[rows][];
int row = 0;
while(scanner.hasNext()) {
    matrix[row] = new String[5];
    for(int i = 0; i < 5;i++) {
        matrix[row][i] = "" + scan.nextInt();
    }
}
```